# Element in plugin won't accept jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

This is a check box modifier plugin. If you have an input of the check box variety, this plugin will basically create a more aesthetically pleasing version of it. However, there seems to be a problem with one of my variables.

Enter the `theLabelSpinner` variable. This variable is supposed to represent a `<span>` element that gets inserted into the label of the corresponding check box (via jQuery). If the current state (value of the check box) is checked, this spinner will move to the right. If it is unchecked, this spinner will remain on the left.

Unfortunately whenever I try to call any jQuery functions on the element, it simply doesn't work. The console doesn't throw an error, in fact, I even successfully logged both of the elements.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.bvCheckbox = function( customOptions ) {

    this.each( function(i) { // Beginning of loop

    var theEl = $(this); //the element
        theID = theEl.attr( 'id' ); //id="" attribute
        theName = theEl.attr( 'name' ); //name="" attribute
        theClass = theEl.attr( 'class' ); //class="" attribute

    var theLabel = $( "label[for='" + theID + "']" ); //the label corresponding to the checkbox element
        theLabelText = theLabel.text();
        theLabelSpinner = theLabel.children( 'span.bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner' );

    /**
     * Initiates the plugin, runs all the functions.
     *
     * */
    function init() { 
        //prepare the checkbox
        prepareCheckbox();

        //initiate current states
        initStates();
    }

    init();

    /**
     * Prepares checkbox and corresponding labels
     * */
    function prepareCheckbox() {
        //rid the label of any text
        theLabel.empty();

        //hide the checkbox
        theEl.hide();

        //add the class 'bv-jquery-checkbox-label'
        theLabel.addClass( 'bv-jquery-checkbox-label' );

        //insert the spinner
        theLabel.append( '<span class="bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner"></span>' )
    }

    /**
     * Sets the initial states for the checkboxes when
     * the page loads
     * */
    function initStates() {

        if ( ! currentState( theEl ) ) {
            console.log( theLabelSpinner ); // I logged it successfully
            theLabelSpinner.hide(); // Problem arises!
        }

    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the current value of the checkbox
     * STATES:
     * --------
     * checked: 1
     * unchecked: 0
     * */
    function currentState() {
        if ( theEl.is( ":checked" ) ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } 

    });//End of loop

}

}(jQuery));
```

The problem occurs during the `initStates` function. This is supposed to initialize the position of the the spinner element, depending on the state of the check box; however, it doesn't work. I even tried a simpler jQuery function such as `.hide()` and none of them worked. Whenever I log the spinners (as I did in the `initStates` function), this gets thrown at me:

```
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor:function, init: function…] script.js:78

[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, jquery: "1.10.2", constructor:function,    init: function…] script.js:78
```

Which means that both elements were successfully logged, meaning that they do exist and I'm not crazy! Can someone please rescue me from the tunnel in which I'm currently residing in. Thanks in advance. Here is the full script in action: [Full Script](http://jsfiddle.net/3jhCM/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you're searching for theLabelSpinner before creating it.

Change the line:

`theLabelSpinner = theLabel.children( 'span.bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner' );`

to:

`theLabelSpinner = null;`

And update:

`theLabel.append( '<span class="bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner"></span>' )`

to:

```
//Create the spinner and hold a reference to it.
theLabelSpinner = $('<span />', {
    'class': 'bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner'
});

//insert the spinner            
theLabel.append(theLabelSpinner);
```

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nEbW2/1/)**</kbd>

If you inspect the DOM in the demo above, you'll see that the spinner has been set to `display:none;` in response to your call to `.hide()`

Comment: Thank you! Your help is much, much obliged! I had gotten serious tunnel vision. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When initializing the spinners the value is set here  (i believe)

```
theLabel.append( '<span class="bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner"></span>' )
```

Have you tried wrapping it with the jQuery selector to create the span as an object such as.

```
theLabel.append( $('<span class="bv-jquery-checkbox-label-spinner"></span>') );
```

If this doesnt work can you post a JSFiddle with a sandpit sample?

**EDIT:**

I forked it and is working now. The problem was both my response before and the fact that labelSpinner was being set before being added to the dom tree.

http://jsfiddle.net/XP5U4/

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, I did post a JSFIDDLE if you're still interested.

Comment: Please check the update and the forked Fiddle (that sounds naughty)